# Android can't build emulator

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.avaca.testlogin"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

I can't understant why I did not change anything and it compiled fine yesterday I need this project for school due in two days.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

[image: ErrorMessage]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with default config like this

```
defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.avaca.testlogin"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multidexenabled true
        }
```

Comment: Didnt work Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: delete .gradle folder on your app folder, clean & try again.

Comment: I deleted it first off i dunno why this problem is occuring i didnt change anything in that file i rebuild it and implement your code i got this error anyway thanks for being so helpful.